# Stop python GUI program from exiting when run from CLI

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, command-line, matplotlib

How can easily I make a blocking GUI app on OS X?

I have a simple python plotting program. When I run it from inside an existing python interactive session, or from within iPython, the GUI window is displayed, and I can see it and interact with it. When I run the `.py` file from the CLI, the GUI flashes and closes immediately.

I would like to run this from the command line and have the GUI remain.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib
    from matplotlib import pyplot
    data = range(1,10)
    fig = pyplot.plot(data)
    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: What platform are you on?  I run this on Linux and the GUI stays up.

Comment: OS X. You are running `python ./foo.py` and it stays up?

Comment: Yeah; Not a great solution, but what happens when you throw in a raw_input or something?

Comment: Yeah that'll do it. Not great, but works...

Comment: So we know that the GUI isn't crashing or anything - it's just forking (like in interactive "ipython -pylab" mode) and then the program ends, sending a close signal to it.  Huh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though interactive mode has been enabled somehow, although I'm not sure where.  Try it like this:

```
def main():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    data = range(1,10)
    fig = plt.plot(data)
    plt.ioff()  # turns interactive mode OFF, should make show() blocking
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```